# I can't get my button to work on my second layout (Android)

Tags: android, button, layout

<strike>I've spent 8 years programming and for 8 years I've been pretty happy, but after using Android Studio for two weeks I already want to</strike>

So here's the deal. I made 2 layouts. One is the default, named `activity_main.xml`, the other is named `graph_layout.xml`. They are both `ConstraintLayout`s (but the same issue occurred when I tried making `graph_layout` a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`, so we can rule that out as a factor).

In `activity_main`, there's a button with the ID, *graph_button_1*. When I click it, it prints to the console "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" (but with more A's) and switches from `activity_main` layout to `graph_layout`. As it should, that's precisely what I designed it to do.

Now, here's the problem. I also have a button in `graph_layout` with the ID, *calc_button_3*. When I click this button, it's supposed to print to the console "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA2" (but with more A's) and then switch from `graph_layout` to `activity_main`. It doesn't do that, though. It prints to the console a little message that, "yes, you did click the button, here are all the details of how you clicked that button" (I'm paraphrasing), but it does not print "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA2" to the console, nor does it switch back to `activity_main`. (If you're wondering, the AAAAA message is just to see whether the `setOnClickListener` functions are actually executing).

Speaking of which, here's what the `setOnClickListener` does for `calc_button_3`:

```
//final Context context = this;
calcButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //I know I can use lambda funcitons, but I wanted to play it safe
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); //This was one of the solutions I found online. It does not do anything.
        //startActivity(intent);
        System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA2");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
});
```

To be fair, I'm a step in the right direction. Before, this function made my app crash. Now, it just does nothing. So...that's a little better, and I'd like to thank the `LayoutInflater` class for making that possible. I'd also like to point out that I'm willing to supply you with any code or extra information you might want to see. I'd send the whole `MainActivity.java` file if I could, but I know from experience the longer I make my question, the less likely people are to answer, and it is a VERY long file.

I've scoured the internet for a solution to this, and while I've found people with a similar problem, none of their solutions worked for me.

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Below, I will attach any code or additional info anyone in the comments asks me to give them:

Comment: I'm not starting a new activity, I'm switching to another layout. Should I start a new activity instead?

Answer (score 0):

You have to start a new activity using intent or if you want to use the same activity then use fragments. and replace fragment layout on button press. but you can not directly use setContentView();

Comment: Would you recommend I use a new activity or the same activity?

Comment: I guess I'm gonna have to use fragments. I should've known. I should've known. When I looked up online how to use multiple layouts, the first result I got just told me "okay, just make another xml file, design its interface, and use setContentView to swap back and forth between layouts". I was like "wow, that actually looks pretty easy." That should've tipped me off. I should've known. NOTHING is easy with android studio. NOTHING! Of course it won't work because that would just make too much sense! Everything must be hard, nothing can be straightforward! GAAAAAAHH!!!

Comment: You can not just always use fragments. fragment can only be use when you like when you use bottom navigation or tab layout etc like WhatsApp. whatsapp use tab layout in main activity and it swipe the fragments when you click on chat or stories.

Comment: That seems to be appropriate for my current situation.

Answer (score 0):

All `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` does is inflate that layout file into its hierarchy of `View` objects, and display that in the current `Activity`. You're still in the same `Activity`, you've just changed its contents.

When you say you're doing this:

> In activity_main, there's a button with the ID, `graph_button_1`. When I click it, it prints to the console "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" (but with more A's) and switches from `activity_main layout` to `graph_layout`.

does that mean you're "switching" by calling `setContentView` there too, instead of starting a different `Activity` that displays `graph_layout`?

---

If so, and all your code for both layouts is in the same `Activity`, then your problem is probably related to the fact you're replacing your `Views` with a new set of objects when you call `setContentView`. If you set up your buttons like this:

```
// a Button from your current view hierarchy gets assigned to this at some point 
val someButton: Button

// just use the lambda, it's literally the same as creating the object under the hood
someButton.setOnClickListener {
    // do a thing
}
```

And then later you call `setContentView(R.layout.some_layout)`, then *whatever `Button` object `someButton` is referencing is no longer on the screen*. So you can't see it, you can't click it. If you just inflated the same layout as before (creating an entirely seperate set of `View` objects) then there's another button in the same place - but you haven't set a click listener on it, so it doesn't do anything.

---

So if you *are* going to go replacing the view hierarchy like this, then you need to perform your `View` setup (like assigning click listeners) when you create those new views. If you just set things up when the `Activity` starts, then it's only applied to the view hierarchy in use at that moment. As soon as you replace it with `setContentView`, that stuff is gone.

So you could write functions that "switch" to one layout or the other by calling `setContentView` and *then* applying the click listeners. Generally speaking though, this isn't how you normally do things in Android. The old way would be to create separate `Activities` for each screen, a more modern approach is using `Fragments` which can be swapped out manually or by using something like the *Navigation* library.

Either way, both those approaches involve configuring your `Activity` or `Fragment` once during setup, making buttons do this or that, and then you're done. Everything's neatly separated and self-contained, instead of you having to swap views out and rewire everything according to the state you want to display. That's just complicating things, and it'll get much worse if you start adding more screens you have to juggle!

I'd recommend at least taking a look at the [*Fragments guide*](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments), or the [Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) component if you have time. The latter has more to learn, but it also handles a lot of complexity for you. It would help to at least have an understanding of the usual way of doing things, anyway!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by View. Literally everything is a View. Anyways, I'm just going to use fragments <strike>because I'm not giving up just yet</strike> because I'm a masochist. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vAI7RSPxOA This is the video I'm going to use to help me through this. Tomorrow. Because I've spent literally all day on this problem, and I'm too tired to literally start over from scratch. Plus, I'm almost 100% sure I'm going to run into 500 bugs while redoing my entire interface, and nothing will be even remotely usable until all 500 bugs are resolved. Goodnight.

Comment: @MathMachine `View`s are specifically the class that UI components derive from - that includes layout containers like `ConstraintLayout` or `LinearLayout`, and widgets like `Button`s or `RecyclerView`s. When you *inflate* a layout XML file, it's really constructing those objects (e.g. calling `Button()`) and setting up the relevant parameters and connecting them together into a hierarchy. When you call `setContentView(R.layout.something)`, it's *inflating* that set of objects, then setting the root `View` in that hierarchy as the thing that should be displayed

Comment: Yes, I understand object inheritance, hence why I said everything is a View. I just don't know which specific Views you were referring to. :/

Comment: @MathMachine I'm not talking about inheritance, I'm talking about a hierarchy of object instances (like a tree) where some are children of others depending on how the layout is defined. If you inflate another copy of the layout with another call to `setContentView`, you get a completely different set of objects that has no connection to the ones you initially inflated and then set up. Those are the sets of Views I'm talking about. I just explained what the View class *is* in case there's some confusion about what's actually going on in terms of objects and what the Activity is displaying